# What is a system of representatives of the residue field in its ring R?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let R be a complete discrete valuation ring, with field of fractions K and residue field $\hat{K}$. Let S be a system of representatives of $\hat{K}$ in R.

Can someone please explain to me what a *system of representatives* is here?

Answer (score 2):

A set of elements of $R$ such that each class modulo the maximal ideal of $R$ contains exactly one element of the set.